Hover effect to on different parts of an image
I want to create an interactive image with CSS where every part of it will reveal a different icon when you hover on it.
I can't figure out how to make it responsive while:

keeping all the parts sized and positioned correctly in relation to each other (so it will all fit together as one big image) and
keeping the revealed icon at the center of the corresponding image part.

This is what I have at the moment:


.circle-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vw;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle-part {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.circle-part img {
  width: 40%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.circle-part:hover .icon {
  opacity: 1;
}

.circle-part.part1 {
  transform: translate(-70%, 35%);
}
.circle-part.part2 {
  transform: translate(-38%, -75%);
}
.circle-part.part3 {
  transform: translate(-5%, -70%);
}
.circle-part.part4 {
  transform: translate(40%, -260%);
}
.circle-part.part5 {
  transform: translate(45%, -35%);
}
.circle-part.part6 {
  transform: translate(45%, 75%);
}
.circle-part.part7 {
  transform: translate(2%, 95%);
}
.circle-part.part8 {
  transform: translate(-1%, 10%);
}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Interactive Image</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="circle-container">
      <div class="circle-part part1">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/43YQH7jK/default-1.png" alt="Part 1" />
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/xdSr9Y2b/hover-1.png" class="icon" alt="Icon 1" />
      </div>
      <div class="circle-part part2">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/7hk3RBh7/default-2.png" alt="Part 2" />
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/ZqPGRgbs/hover-2.png" class="icon" alt="Icon 2" />
      </div>
      <div class="circle-part part3">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Y9gNbcrM/default-3.png" alt="Part 3" />
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/G2cZsQ9L/hover-3.png" class="icon" alt="Icon 3" />
      </div>
      <div class="circle-part part4">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/cJPMR1NF/default-4.png" alt="Part 4" />
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/nz0NKDQv/hover-4.png" class="icon" alt="Icon 4" />
      </div>
      <div class="circle-part part5">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/j24HYzn1/default-5.png" alt="Part 5" />
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/PJJ9S5m0/hover-5.png" class="icon" alt="Icon 5" />
      </div>
      <div class="circle-part part6">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/WpG6ZPY7/default-6.png" alt="Part 6" />
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/KjWVwhfj/hover-6.png" class="icon" alt="Icon 6" />
      </div>
      <div class="circle-part part7">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/7YX3BnkG/default-7.png" alt="Part 7" />
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/sfHtv5zz/hover-7.png" class="icon" alt="Icon 7" />
      </div>
      <div class="circle-part part8">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/yY7hXrwC/default-8.png" alt="Part 8" />
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/gkw1RrcZ/hover-8.png" class="icon" alt="Icon 8" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



I also read about image mapping, but I don't know if that would work for this or how to go about it.
this is what I'm trying to achieve.

Frankly, use an SVG, much simpler, scalable and responsive.

I do have it as an SVG as well. Would much appreciate a short rundown of why that would be better/how to go about it.

You can have a look at this SO answer link

Each shape can be an individual path in g group in an overall SVG. Each with it's own fill, stroke and internal icon image if you want. An SVG is  vector and so more scalable and an SVG is more responsive than in actual <img>. And each g is individually addressable/selectable with CSS etc.

If you want to stick with an 'ordinary' image then position everything in relation to that image in % terms.

Thanks for guiding me in the SVG direction. I don't know what to mark as the answer, but this ended up being the perfect fit for this task, for all the reasons @Paulie_D pointed out.

Some pointers.

It is better to make the container of the image to be width: 40% rather than the image itself width: 40% so you can center the icon more easily, and not have 60% empty space that might obscure other parts.
I removed the display: flex from the .circle-container as it might add "randomness" because it messes with widths and positions of the items.
Now the image is responsive since all units are %. Only issue is it isn't the image you intended at all. For this you'd need to re-position the parts.



.circle-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
  /*
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  */
}

.circle-part {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  width: 40%;
}

.circle-part img {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}


.circle-part img.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.circle-part:hover .icon {
  opacity: 1;
}

.circle-part.part1 {
  transform: translate(-70%, 35%);
}

.circle-part.part2 {
  transform: translate(-38%, -75%);
}

.circle-part.part3 {
  transform: translate(-5%, -70%);
}

.circle-part.part4 {
  transform: translate(40%, -260%);
}

.circle-part.part5 {
  transform: translate(45%, -35%);
}

.circle-part.part6 {
  transform: translate(45%, 75%);
}

.circle-part.part7 {
  transform: translate(2%, 95%);
}

.circle-part.part8 {
  transform: translate(-1%, 10%);
}
<div class="circle-container">
  <div class="circle-part part1">
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/43YQH7jK/default-1.png" alt="Part 1" />
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/xdSr9Y2b/hover-1.png" class="icon" alt="Icon 1" />
  </div>
  <div class="circle-part part2">
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/7hk3RBh7/default-2.png" alt="Part 2" />
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/ZqPGRgbs/hover-2.png" class="icon" alt="Icon 2" />
  </div>
  <div class="circle-part part3">
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Y9gNbcrM/default-3.png" alt="Part 3" />
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/G2cZsQ9L/hover-3.png" class="icon" alt="Icon 3" />
  </div>
  <div class="circle-part part4">
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/cJPMR1NF/default-4.png" alt="Part 4" />
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/nz0NKDQv/hover-4.png" class="icon" alt="Icon 4" />
  </div>
  <div class="circle-part part5">
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/j24HYzn1/default-5.png" alt="Part 5" />
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/PJJ9S5m0/hover-5.png" class="icon" alt="Icon 5" />
  </div>
  <div class="circle-part part6">
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/WpG6ZPY7/default-6.png" alt="Part 6" />
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/KjWVwhfj/hover-6.png" class="icon" alt="Icon 6" />
  </div>
  <div class="circle-part part7">
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/7YX3BnkG/default-7.png" alt="Part 7" />
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/sfHtv5zz/hover-7.png" class="icon" alt="Icon 7" />
  </div>
  <div class="circle-part part8">
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/yY7hXrwC/default-8.png" alt="Part 8" />
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/gkw1RrcZ/hover-8.png" class="icon" alt="Icon 8" />
  </div>
</div>




Simple and neat (+1)
